# Following date conversion query in Snowflake is not working

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

A varchar column in a table contains dates in '05/13/2019 20:48:13 PM' format. It can contain either a single date or many dates concatenated with pipe |. I use this query to get the very first one and try to convert it to timestamp.

```
Select (CASE WHEN  charindex('AM', COMPL_DATE)>=1 OR   charindex('PM', COMPL_DATE) >= 1
        THEN TO_TIMESTAMP ( SPLIT_PART( COMPL_DATE, '|' , 1), 'MM/DD/YYYY hh24:mi:ss AM')
        ELSE TO_TIMESTAMP ( SPLIT_PART( COMPL_DATE, '|' , 1), 'MM/DD/YYYY hh:mi:ss')
     END 
    ) from some_table.
```

I get this error
*Can't parse '03/23/2019 20:56:22 PM' as timestamp with format 'MM/DD/YYYY hh24:mi:ss AM'*.

It is not that it fails for all the rows. There are some rows for which it fails.
However when I use this data to run separately, like this -

```
with tab as ( select  '03/23/2019 20:56:22 PM' COMPL_DATE from dual )
SELECT 
  (CASE WHEN  charindex('AM',COMPL_DATE)>=1 OR   charindex('PM',COMPL_DATE) >= 1
        THEN  TO_TIMESTAMP ( SPLIT_PART( COMPL_DATE, '|' , 1), 'MM/DD/YYYY hh:mi:ss AM')
        ELSE  TO_TIMESTAMP ( SPLIT_PART( COMPL_DATE, '|' , 1), 'MM/DD/YYYY hh24:mi:ss')
   END 
   ) result
FROM tab ;
```

It works fine.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: and what happens if you use your second query on a row where it fails? (like find that row by some other ID value or sth). Because this might be a whitespace issue, so something the code does see but we don't

Comment: Please convert your column to datetime like this and try ``COMPL_DATE:: TIMESTAMP``

Comment: ``` 
COMPL_DATE::TIMESTAMP``` is not helping

Answer (score 1):

Using the combination of the 24 hour clock and AM/PM is not allowed:

'MM/DD/YYYY hh**24**:mi:ss **AM**'

```
HH24 - Two digits for hour (00 through 23); am/pm NOT allowed.
```

Try: 'MM/DD/YYYY hh12:mi:ss AM'

Comment: Tried all possible combinations, error remains the same - *Can't parse '09/26/2019 05:27:56 AM' as timestamp with format 'MM/DD/YYYY hh24:mi:ss'*

Comment: select  TO_TIMESTAMP ( '09/26/2019 05:27:56 AM', 'MM/DD/YYYY hh12:mi:ss AM');

works when i try it. Notice i change the 24 to 12.

Answer (score 0):

It could be related with the extra space characters on your date string. I noticed that the web interface does not show the extra space characters in error messages so I'll contact with the development team to fix the space characters of the results in web interface.

Here's a sample query:

```
select  TO_TIMESTAMP ( '03/23/2019 20:56:22   PM', 'MM/DD/YYYY hh24:mi:ss AM');
```

The error message which you will see in the web interface:

```
Can't parse '03/23/2019 20:56:22 PM' as timestamp with format 'MM/DD/YYYY hh24:mi:ss AM'
```

If you run the same query on Snowflake CLI, you can see the error clearly:

```
PUBLIC>select  TO_TIMESTAMP ( '03/23/2019 20:56:22   PM', 'MM/DD/YYYY hh24:mi:ss AM');
```

100096 (22007): Can't parse '03/23/2019 20:56:22   PM' as timestamp with format 'MM/DD/YYYY hh24:mi:ss AM'

Could you verify the dates in your column?

Comment: I tried getting the row/data for which it fails by suppressing the error by using 'TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP' and its length - and found the length displayed are only expected values 19 or 22. 
Not sure why it fails only for some. BTW you're right when I ran this query in CLI, I got ***100096 (22007): Can't parse '03/23/2019 20:56:22 PM' as timestamp with format 'MM/DD/YYYY hh24:mi:ss AM'*** error